# WordPress custom metabox not saving data or display

Tags: php, wordpress

After two days of research and questions without answer, today someone has suggested a way to add a custom metabox field to the Wordpress images. My scope is to add a URL when the images are uploaded or modified and for now I'm only able to display the input field where user can add the URL, but the input will not be saved and I'm unable to get it back on the front-end.

I want to use this custom metabox function with the `get_post_gallery()` that will output the URLs of the images I've added inside a gallery, but I don't know how to combine this, and I need to fix the saving of the inserted URL. Can anyone help me or guide through the implementation?

```
<?php
 function add_image_link()
 {
   add_meta_box(
     'image_link_box',
     'Link image to url',
     'image_link_field',
     'attachment'
   ); 
 }
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_attachment', 'add_image_link' );

 function image_link_field( $post )
 {
   ?>
   <label for="image-link">Link URL</label>
   <input type="text" name="image_link" id="image-link" class="postbox">
   <?php
 }

 function save_image_link( $post_id )
 {
   if( array_key_exists( 'image_link', $_POST ) ){
     update_post_meta(
       $post_id,
       'image_link_url',
       $_POST['image_link']
     );
   }

 }
 add_action( 'save_post_attachment', 'save_image_link' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save and display input field value(image_link_url), Try below code

```
function image_link_field( $post )
 {
   $url = get_post_meta($post->ID,'image_link_url',true)
   ?>
   <label for="image-link">Link URL</label>
   <input type="text" name="image_link" id="image-link" value="<?php ($url)? $url : '';?>" class="postbox">
   <?php
 }

 function save_image_link( $post_id )
 {
    $image_link = isset( $_POST['image_link'] ) ? $_POST['image_link'] : false;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'image_link_url', $image_link );
    return;
 }
 add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'save_image_link' );
```

Kindly note that , in the edit media screen when you update attachment, **edit_attachment** hook is called instead of **save_post_attachment**.

Let me know how it helps you!

Comment: I'm having trouble in saving the info and to display the images of the gallery using a custom shortcode, this because the shortcode will load all the media library attachment and not only the page or post attached media.

Answer (score 0):

Try this It's working fine (custom meta box not saving data or display in wordpress)

```
function add_image_link() {

add_meta_box(
    'image_link_box',
    __( 'Title:', 'Link image to url' ),
    'image_link_field',
    ['post', 'page']
);
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_attachment', 'add_image_link' );


function image_link_field( $post ) {

// Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
wp_nonce_field( 'custom_nonce', 'custom_nonce' );

 $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_link_box', true );
echo '<label for="image_link_box">Link URL</label>';
echo '<input type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" name="image_link_box" id="image_link_box" class="postbox">';

}


function save_image_link($post_id)
{
if (array_key_exists('image_link_box', $_POST)) {
    update_post_meta(
        $post_id,
        'image_link_box',
        $_POST['image_link_box']
    );
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_image_link');
```

Comment: I need it for the images wp `$screen` only, using `['post', 'page']` will add the custom meta for the posts and pages and this will not be useful for my scope

Comment: please add screenshots

Comment: I need the custom metabo only for images attached to a post or a page and not for the pages and posts, your example will add the metabox to posts and pages, but this isn't what I need, the url field I want to add is needed only for images :)

Comment: Please check this link https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1--wp-22291

Comment: HI sisaln i think your problem is shot out. Please let me know if any issue